# Difference between window.open("link") and window.open("link", "_blank")

Tags: javascript, window.open

I read that `_blank` is the default value of the name parameter on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). So I was wondering if there is any benefit to adding this parameter or is it just a waste of time?

Comment: @PatrikBego — Looking at the documentation for the `target` attribute of the `a` element in **HTML** is not a good way to get insight into the behaviour of the second argument to the `open` function in **JavaScript**!

Comment: I suggest using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) in preference to w3schools.

Comment: I doubt it (I certainly hope not, that would be really jerky). w3schools will forever be in my bad books for using a misleading name, but its content has at least improved a bit over time. (I can't help but note that MDN doesn't tell you about the `target` default, but w3schools does. Doh! :-) ) It was likely that they felt the question lacked research effort, but unless one of them pipes up, it's impossible to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference to what happens. The [`window` specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#the-window-object) defines the `target` parameter as being a string with a default value of `"_blank"`:

> `WindowProxy? open(optional USVString url = "", optional DOMString target = "_blank", optional [LegacyNullToEmptyString] DOMString features = "");
> getter object (DOMString name);`

*(My emphasis.)*

So not providing it at all or providing `"_blank"` does the same thing. It's up to you whether including it is in some way clearer (or alternatively, unnecessary clutter).